# Error: Plugin 0 specified in "/my dir/node_modules/babel-preset-php/src/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default"

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, npm, babeljs

I am trying to convert PHP script to js using `babel-preset-php` but I am getting this error-

```
Error: Plugin 0 specified in "/media/deep/5738c180-2397-451b-b0b5-df09b7ad951e1/deepx/Documents/TestingAll/node_modules/babel-preset-php/src/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "/media/deep/5738c180-2397-451b-b0b5-df09b7ad951e1/deepx/Documents/TestingAll/node_modules/babel-preset-php/src/index.js")
    at Plugin.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
    at Function.normalisePlugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:265:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:323:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
```

I installed the preset with `npm i -S babel-preset-php`.
I set `.babelrc` to

```
{
  "presets": ["php"]
}
```

I installed the CLI with `npm i -g babel-cli`. Then I created a simple PHP file that only contains simple code:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
```

And when I run the transpiler with `babel file.php -o file.js`, I am getting that error.

---

`package.json` -

```
{
  "name": "testingall",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-php": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.6",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

`node version - v12.18.4`.

`babel version - 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)`

How can solve that?

Comment: Does it work if you use `"babel-preset-php": "^1.0.0",` instead?

Comment: Okay, it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
"babel-preset-php": "^2.0.0",
```

is for Babel 7.x. Since you've installed Babel 6.x, you need to use

```
"babel-preset-php": "^1.0.0",
```